# Is it possible to write a C++ function that stringizes?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, stringification

How would you go if you had to write a proper C++ function that does the same as the operator '#' in macros?

It would be useful if it were possible to do it at runtime.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Do you have an example usage?

Comment: I would go crazy because you can't do that.

Comment: An example would be very helpful.  At *runtime*, there isn't much available to stringize that isn't already a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. What you are basically asking for is this...

```
void function(int someargname)
{
    std::cout << #someargname << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    function(3);
    return 0;
}
```

And expecting to get "someargname" as the output instead of "3". The language simply does not support that syntax.